# GoogleConversionPing Undefined symbol

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I am developing an IOS application. Also useing GoogleConversionTrackingSDK. I added to project;
GoogleConversionPing.h, libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a files. But I am getting this error message

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GoogleConversionPing", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Am also receiving same error. Can you please share me the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think those don't compile on arm64 so if you don't use a newer version of googleTracking you have to remove arm64 from the `Valid architectures` in `build settings`